# Where would I get Microsoft Chart Control sample codes?

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone please tell me where would I get Microsoft Chart Control sample codes ?
Link will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link --> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

These samples demonstrate how to use the following features in Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework:

1. All supported chart types.
2. Data series, chart areas, axes, legends, labels, titles, and more.
3. Data Binding
4. Data manipulation, such as copying, splitting, merging, alignment, grouping, sorting, searching, filtering, and more.
5. Statistical formulas and financial formulas.
6. Advanced chart appearance, such as 3D, anti-aliasing, lighting, perspective, and more.
7. Chart rendering.
8. Events and Customizations.
9. Interactivity and AJAX.

Comment: Thanks kushalwaikar for the more details.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Answer (score 1):

if your talking about the ASP.Net Chart controls you can download the demos from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Answer (score 0):

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart